# Kolmogorov continuity theorem for Banach space valued random processes

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am interested in [the Kolmogorov continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem). I would like to know if this theorem holds for Banach space valued random processes (probably separable Banach space). I cannot find a paper or a textbook that contains a version of the Kolmogorov continuity theorem for Banach space valued random processes. My questions are as follows:

1. does the Kolmogorov continuity theorem hold for Banach space valued random processes;
2. where can I find a paper or a textbook that contains the statement and the proof of the Kolmogorov continuity theorem for Banach space valued random processes?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theorem 3.23 on Kallenberg's ["Foundations of Modern Probability"](https://books.google.com/books?id=L6fhXh13OyMC&pg=PA57) (the page might not be available in Google Books :( ). You just need a complete metric space and $\mathbb{R}^d$ as index space.

In my opinion Kallenberg's book is THE source for general theorems in probability :)